# Issue with Microsoft PDF Printer and PrintVisual

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I figured out printing a WPF UserControl with the default printer (which is actually the MS PDF printer).

My code is something like this:

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

dialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

//Layout and Measure the control
...

// Print Visual
dialog.PrintVisual(userControl, name);
```

The printed pdf is like I expected.

Can I set the filename in the printer programatically without user interaction?

**UPDATE:**

My real problem is to find an easy way to print out a WPF-UserControl to pdf without any dialogs.

**UPDATE2 (Solution):**

So here is my solution which was actually my plan b:

EDITED:

1. Write XPS File with a XpsDocumentWriter
2. convert XPS to PDF via PDFsharp library

Comment: See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.printdialog?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) on the PrintVisual class: *... you can use the PrintDocument method without ever opening the dialog. In that sense, the control can be used as an unseen printing component ...*

Comment: it's actually not the PrintDialog that shows up. if i would print to a normal printer there is no dialog shown. but in my case (MS PDF Printer) the save file dialog shows up and i don't want that.

Comment: @JoMue In your Update2, you said : "print visual as XPS file". But how print as XPS without Dialog ? If i choose "Microsoft XPS Document Writer", I have a dialog.

Comment: @StevenPF i'm sorry for confusing. I actually ment writing the XPS-file with a XpsDocumentWriter